# How can I redirect the output of current script to eg less if paginator is set?

Tags: linux, bash

I have got a set of scripts that all source some common context:

```bsh
DEFAULT_PAGINATION=''

ownContext=$HOME/.config/exploitation/context.sh
if [ -f "$ownContext" ]; then
  # shellcheck source=$HOME/.config/exploitation/context.sh
  . "$ownContext"
fi
```

That way anybody can override the default config: some locations, help flags and in this case, pagination.

To automatically redirect to less, for instance, I have tried that:

```bsh
# DEFAULT_PAGINATION is the default pagination tool (a program)
# OUTPUT_PAGINATION_FILE acts as an include guard, or contains a filename

if [ -n "$DEFAULT_PAGINATION" ] && [ -z "$OUTPUT_PAGINATION_FILE" ]; then
  paginate() {
    $DEFAULT_PAGINATION "$OUTPUT_PAGINATION_FILE" # paginate tempfile
  }
  trap paginate exit
  OUTPUT_PAGINATION_FILE=$(mktemp)
  export OUTPUT_PAGINATION_FILE
  exec 1<&- # close stdout
  exec 1<>"$OUTPUT_PAGINATION_FILE" # redirect stdout to a temp file
fi
```

and `export DEFAULT_PAGINATION=less` in the other context file, but it doesn't work. Any idea ?

Plus, that solution does not allow `export DEFAULT_PAGINATION="less +F"` and on the fly redirection. Is there a solution to do that ?

<sub>P.S. the `bash` tag is intentionnal</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can be done only by sourcing something. It can be done with a custom interpreter (wrapper).

Save this example piece of code as `bash-pager`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -t 1 ] && [ -n "$PAGER" ]; then
    bash "$@" | sh -c "$PAGER"
else
    exec bash "$@"
fi
```

Make it executable (`chmod +x bash-pager`). Then change the shebang of these scripts you mentioned to

```
#!/full/path/to/bash-pager
```

or maybe (if `bash-pager` is reachable via `$PATH`) to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash-pager
```

In effect, if you have `PAGER` set and exported, the scripts will use it.

---

I used `PAGER` because it's [kinda standard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213367/108618). You may want your `bash-pager` look more like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

ownContext="$HOME/.config/exploitation/context.sh"
if [ -f "$ownContext" ]; then
  . "$ownContext"
fi

DEFAULT_PAGINATION="${DEFAULT_PAGINATION:-$PAGER}"

if [ -t 1 ] && [ -n "$DEFAULT_PAGINATION" ]; then
    bash "$@" | sh -c "$DEFAULT_PAGINATION"
else
    exec bash "$@"
fi
```

Notes:

- As you can see `$DEFAULT_PAGINATION` is used with `sh -c`, so you can pass a command with arguments (e.g. `DEFAULT_PAGINATION='cat -n'`) or a pipeline.
- `[ -t 1 ]` checks if stdout is a terminal. Thanks to this precaution you can still run `one_of_your_scripts | whatever` and `DEFAULT_PAGINATION` will not interfere.
- `PAGER` can still be used. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122845/108618).
- I don't know what `context.sh` is supposed to do. Few concerns:

  - `context.sh` may do something you don't want in the context of interpreter, so sourcing it in `bash-pager` may not be desired.
  - `context.sh` may do something you explicitly want in your script(s), so you'd like to source it in every script anyway.
  - `context.sh` may require `bash`. Note `bash-pager` is designed to wrap over `bash` but its interpreter (shebang) is `/bin/sh`. Changing to `bash` is trivial though.
  - `context.sh` may use `set` to alter `$@`. If it does then `"$@"` later in `bash-pager` may not expand to what we need.

  This is for you to solve. Note the interpreter only needs `DEFAULT_PAGINATION`/`PAGER`. You can tell users to set and export one of these in their `profile` (if they want the functionality). Then `bash-pager` won't need to source anything.

Comment: That's brilliant. Context is some definitions i dont want to put in my coworker's .profile.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `script1.sh` you want to paginate using `less`.

You can create a wrapper script that will paginate the `script1.sh` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/path/to/script1.sh | less
```

When you run the wrapper script it will run the `script1.sh` and paginate it using `less`.

*Is there any reason why this doesn't work for you?*

Comment: Yeah, there is ! Imagine I have a set of scripts ; all of which source some context.sh file. Can you imagine doing something in the context file so that every thing written after sourcing the context by the super-scripts is redirected toward some pagination ?

Comment: Maybe `exec 2>&1 | less +F` would work ? gotta test that

Comment: I don't think it's possible to redirect the output of the script from within the script. However, I don't get why you don't wrap each of the scripts individually and paginate using what I suggested above. If you don't like the part when you need to wrap the scripts one by one you can create a wrapper that will take care of the pagination for all of the scripts. I could create a small example for you but maybe it's going to be more useful if you include some sample code with your question.

Comment: I have put together a small example that shows how you can paginate a set of scripts without creating a separate wrapper for each of them: https://github.com/curusarn/superuser-question-paginate/

Comment: If there is something specific about your scripts please post a sample code.